What is the maximum timeout for Firestore JS client httpsCallable timeout?
Issue
I keep getting this error after 5mins and 1sec after executing the code
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[FirebaseError: internal] {
  code: 'functions/internal',
  customData: undefined,
  details: undefined
}

Node.js v22.1.0

This is my client code
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const functions = getFunctions(app, "us-central1");
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);
const testFunction = httpsCallable(functions, 'doTask', {timeout: 1200000})
testFunction({url: "url", vid: "test6"})
.then((result) => console.log(result))

My function require sometime between 10-15 mins to execute. The function doesn't show any error and continues to run successfully after the client crashed. I tried bypassing the function to return instantly and the client worked just fine. However I can't seems to find any documentation indicating the limit on timeout on JS client.

That error message doesn't say anything about being a timeout.  If it was a timeout, I'd expect the error message to specifically say that.  "functions/internal" typically means the backend function had a problem.
But if you want to change the timeout, this has been documented in the API documentation for third parameter of httpsCallable(), which is a HttpsCallableOptions object.  Use the timeout property.  It looks like you're already know that though.  You can expect it to go as long as the underlying maximum timeout for the client platform, which could possibly vary depending on your browser or OS.
You should be aware that you might also need to set the timeout in your backend callable definition as well (which you aren't showing here).  Use the timeoutSeconds property of the HttpsOptions argument that you pass to onCall().
Also keep in mind that your code is connecting to an emulator, which doesn't have the exact same behavior as production.  It is just an approximation meant to make development easier.  It could have a problem as well.
If you think the SDK or backend SDK isn't working correctly and have a clear, simple code to reproduce (both backend and client), then you should file a bug report on GitHub.

I forgot to mention that before putting timeout property it was actually showing timeout error, now I added timeout to both client and server. The error seems to be consistently at 5mins that's why I wonder If it has something to do with timeout. I'm confused because my backend (function) doesn't show any error so I have no idea what the cause is.
